# Values are changing while matching levels in R.

Tags: r, statistics, levels

I have 2 variables x and y. In X I have only 1 value with 1 level. I want to match levels of y to x. After matching levels, level's are matching but value of X is changing. Why this is so ?

```
x = as.factor(c(3))    
> x
3
Levels: 3

y = as.factor(c(2,3,4))
> y
2 3 4
Levels: 2 3 4
```

Output -

> levels(x) = levels(y)
>
> ```
> print(x)
>  2
> ```
>
> Levels: 2 3 4

The initial value of X was 3 now its 2.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? are you trying to show which value in y = x?

Comment: levels(x) = levels(y) is telling r to pass the levels of y (2,3,4) to x, because x is of length 1, it is only taking the first level of y (2)

Comment: `x <- factor(3, levels(y))`

Comment: @griffnevo - I just wanted to match levels in both variables. For example levels in the training data and testing data should be same.

Comment: This will add the missing levels to `x` without changing it's original value - `levels(x) <- c(levels(x), levels(y))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this occurs because R presents the new level and not the value. 
For example, if you will do `as.numeric(x)` it will present 1 and not 3.

```
x <- as.factor(c(3))  
as.numeric(x)
```

> [1] 1

However, if you will unfactor the variable using `varhandle::unfactor()`, it will present the "real" value.

```
varhandle::unfactor(x)
```

> [1] 3

Thus, when you do `levels(x) <- levels(y)` you don't relevel/refactor the levels of x to be like y - you adjusting/changing the levels and values.

```
x <- as.factor(c(3))  
y <- as.factor(c(2,3,4))
levels(x) <- levels(y)
unfactor(x)
```

> [1] 2

Doing this`x <- factor(x, levels = union(levels(x), levels(y)))` will solve your problem.

```
x <- as.factor(c(3))  
y <- as.factor(c(2,3,4))
x
```

> [1] 3 Levels: 3

```
x <- factor(x, levels = union(levels(x), levels(y)))
x
```

> [1] 3 Levels: 2 3 4

```
unfactor(x)
```

> [1] 3

Thank you @pieca for the comment.

Comment: One note: if `x` contains values that are not present in `y` this solution will generate `NAs`
To prevent this run: `x <- factor(x, levels = union(levels(x), levels(y)))`

Comment: Worked for me Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

R factors are really positive integer vectors which have a `levels`-attribute that is used as a lookup "table". What happened in your example is that the value of x was 1 (since there was only one item in `levels(x)` that happened to be the character "3"). When you replaced the `levels`-attribute with the character vector: c( '2', '3', '4') the consequence was using `1` as an index to that vector returning the first item in the levels attribute which was now the character-"2".

It's really fairly dangerous to go around changing levels of factors. If you wanted to expand the levels, the safe way to do it would be something along these lines:

```
x <- factor( as.character(x), levels = union(levels(x), levels(y) ) )
```